# ¿Cómo reemplazar el valor del calculo de un input si es menor que el valor mínimo establecido como resultado final?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hola quiero armar un cotizador de precios el cual tenga un valor mínimo de $3500, pero no logro hacer que el resultado final cambie si este es menos al mínimo establecido.

Otro problema es que el calculo no se realiza automáticamente, tengo que apretar Tab o Enter para que realice el cálculo.

La verdad que estoy recién empezando y se que debe ser fácil par muchos esto pero bueno, no he podido resolverlo.

```js
function multiplicar(){
 m1 = document.getElementById("multiplicando-fijos").value;
 m2 = document.getElementById("multiplicador-fijos").value;
 r = m1*m2;
 document.getElementById("resultado_1").value = r;
 }

function multiplicar2(){
 m1 = document.getElementById("multiplicando-itinerantes").value;
 m2 = document.getElementById("multiplicador-itinerantes").value;
 r = m1*m2;
 document.getElementById("resultado_2").value = r;
 }


function sumar(){
  var total = 0;
  $(".monto").each(function() {
    if (isNaN(parseFloat($(this).val()))) {
      total += 0;
    } else {
      total += parseFloat($(this).val());
      document.getElementById('Total').value = total;
    }
  }); 


}


document.getElementById('multiplicando-fijos').addEventListener('keydown', inputCharacters);
document.getElementById('multiplicando-itinerantes').addEventListener('keydown', inputCharacters);

function inputCharacters(event) {
 
  if (event.keyCode == 13) {
    document.getElementById('resultado_2').focus();
  }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="multiplicar-fijos">
  <div>
    <input type="text" id="multiplicando-fijos" value="" onChange="multiplicar();" />
  <input type="text" id="multiplicador-fijos" class="" value="75" onChange="multiplicar();" readonly="readonly" />
  <input type="text" id="resultado_1" class="monto" onkeyup="sumar();" readonly="readonly"/><span id="Costo"></span>
  </div>
  <div>
  <input type="text" id="multiplicando-itinerantes" value="" onChange="multiplicar2();" />
  <input type="text" id="multiplicador-itinerantes" class="" value="275" onChange="multiplicar2();" readonly="readonly" />
  <input type="text" id="resultado_2" class="monto" onkeyup="sumar();" readonly="readonly"/>
  </div>
  <div>
  <span>El resultado es: </span> <input type="text" id="Total" onchange="cambio(this)" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

¿Por que utilizas `document.getElementById` si ya estas usando jQuery?

Lo que te esta causando el problema es que a los input `multiplicando-fijos` y `multiplicando-itinerantes` le estas asignando el evento `change`. Es por esa razon que no se actualiza hasta que cambie, el evento que debes utilizar es el `onkeyup` o `onkeydown`.

La funcion `sumar` es llamada dentro de las funciones `multiplicar` y `multiplicar2` para mostrar el resultado a medida que cambias los valores.

Abajo te dejo un ejemplo de tu codigo, para que lo revises y lo adaptes a lo que nesecitas.

```js
var minimo = 3500;

function multiplicar(){
  var m1 = $("#multiplicando-fijos").val();
  var m2 = $("#multiplicador-fijos").val();
 
  $("#resultado_1").val(m1 * m2);
  sumar();
}

function multiplicar2(){
  var m1 = $("#multiplicando-itinerantes").val();
  var m2 = $("#multiplicador-itinerantes").val();
 
  $("#resultado_2").val(m1 * m2);
  sumar();
}


function sumar(){
  var total = 0;
  $(".monto").each(function() {
    if (!isNaN(parseFloat($(this).val()))) {
    total += parseFloat($(this).val());
    }
  });
  
  if(total >= minimo){
    $("#Total").val(total);
  } else {
    $("#Total").val(minimo);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="multiplicar-fijos">
  <div>
  <input type="text" id="multiplicando-fijos" onkeyup="multiplicar();" />
  <input type="text" id="multiplicador-fijos" value="75" readonly="readonly" />
  <input type="text" id="resultado_1" class="monto" readonly="readonly"/><span id="Costo"></span>
  </div>
  <div>
  <input type="text" id="multiplicando-itinerantes" onkeyup="multiplicar2();" />
  <input type="text" id="multiplicador-itinerantes" value="275" readonly="readonly" />
  <input type="text" id="resultado_2" class="monto" readonly="readonly"/>
  </div>
  <div>
  <span>El resultado es: </span> <input type="text" id="Total" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Por cierto tambien puedes utilizar el manejador `keypress` de jQuery.

> [Selectors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/): jQuery ofrece un poderoso conjunto de herramientas para hacer coincidir un conjunto de elementos en un documento.
>
> [keypress](https://api.jquery.com/keypress/): Vincula un controlador al evento de JavaScript de "pulsación de tecla".

Comment: Claro, entiendo, si recién estoy empezando con todo esto. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda. Ahora bien, para que el valor final tenga un minimo de $3500 como lo logro?? Ese tema me tiene loco, no logro saber como resolverlo.

Comment: En la funcion `sumar` ya estaba el `if...else` que nesecitas para lo del valor minimo, solo que en el `else` le coloque un valor vacio, de esta forma quedaba a tu criterio que hacer. Igual actualizare la respuesta para agregar el minimo en el `else`.